# help with search box

Tags: calendar

I am designing a screen for a room booking system. The system manages rooms across multiple office locations. This is a localised view for Glasgow:

This is a month view screen:

[image]

When a user clicks a day they will go to a 'view room schedules' for that day.

I have included a fast track search for when a user can simply type into a search box the location of an office, the time and the date. The system returns rooms available for those criteria.

**My question: is my design of the search tool valid? Should I incorporate the date into the search box? (I think this makes better sense from a layout point of view but am wary that incorrect date formats might be entered.)**

Comment: Is "Glasgow" the name of the room, or the name of the city where there may be multiple rooms available for booking?

Comment: glasgow is the name of the city where there will be multiple rooms available for booking

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a date drop down instead of allowing the user to choose their own.

If you have data that is relatively static that you want users to be able to choose through it lowers the chance of them messing up the entry in the search and not getting the desired result if you limit the possibility of user error.

Also consider if there are ranges, I.E you want them to be able to choose between next Tuesday through next Thursday, you can just add a second drop down in.